# This request is not authorized to perform this operation. Azure blobClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I have the following code to return a list of containers using the `WindowsAzure.Storage` nuget package:

```
public static class AzureBlobStorageClient
{
    public static CloudBlobClient GetClient(string AccountName = "foo", string AccountKey = "bar" )
    {
        try
        {

            var connectionString = $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={AccountName};AccountKey={AccountKey};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            IRetryPolicy exponentialRetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), 10);
            blobClient.DefaultRequestOptions.RetryPolicy = exponentialRetryPolicy;
            return blobClient;
        }
        catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error returned from the service: {0}", ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static void DeleteContainer(CloudBlobContainer container)
    {
        var result = container.DeleteIfExistsAsync().Result;
    }

    public static List<CloudBlobContainer> GetContainers()
    {
        var client = GetClient();
        BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        List<CloudBlobContainer> results = new List<CloudBlobContainer>();
        do
        {
            var response = client.ListContainersSegmentedAsync(continuationToken).Result;
            continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
            results.AddRange(response.Results);
        }
        while (continuationToken != null);

        return results;
    }

}
```

when i run this, i get the following error on client.ListContainersSegmentedAsync(continuationToken).Result :

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)'

and I can't see how to set the authorization for the request.

My question is how to get past this error message

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Please see my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129973/get-azureblobcontent-throwing-error-when-run-from-azure-automation-account.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Thanks to @gaurav Mantri for this answer.

The issue was my client IP was not added to the firewall rules for the storage account.

To change this go to :

Storage accounts > {yourAccount} > Networking > Firewalls and Virtual networks

and add your IP address

Comment: +1'd ...so annoyingly obvious!  Yet whenever I work from a remote location, I keep forgetting to add my new IP to the firewalls...   thinking instead my errors are due to Azure Functions updates that have broken everything overnight....   welcome to my morning! :)

Comment: yay for secure solutions!

Comment: It should be the public IP address can be found by curl ifconfig.co

Answer (score 1):

Please note that after enabling all or adding your ip addressed in to whitelist it will take around 1 minute to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the user doesn't have permission to perform the action. Go to IAM and do the role assignment required to perform the action. I had similar situation of not able to create cobtainer in an SA. It worked after assigning contributer role to my login.