# Azure Data Lake: This request is not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-virtual-network

This question is not a duplicate of [This request is not authorized to perform this operation. Azure blobClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130784/this-request-is-not-authorized-to-perform-this-operation-azure-blobclient)

I want to access an Azure Data Lake from an Azure Function. I use Managed Identity and have assigned an "Owner" role for this function in my Data Lake IAM tab. Everything works but only, when I allow "All networks" in my data lake. As soon as I switch to "Selected networks", I get "This request is not authorized to perform this operation" even though I added all outbound IP addresses of my Azure Function to the firewall rules of my data lake.

I added a call to https://api.ipify.org in my Azure Function to see its public IP address. I also use `socket.gethostbyname()` to get the resolved IP address of the host name of the data lake (just to check if this potentially gets resolved to a private IP within Microsoft's data center but it's not, it's a public IP)

[image]

The outbound IP of my function also appears in my Firewall rules:

[image]

and still I get

> Error] Executed 'Functions.json-deserialize-eventhub' (Failed,
> Id=10554e46-2f5e-42a7-a9f7-a95dad1b4e30, Duration=1063ms)Result:
> FailureException: HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to
> perform this
> operation.RequestId:84928ea9-201e-0092-5a97-d46e78000000Time:2020-12-17T17:07:38.2792923ZErrorCode:AuthorizationFailureError:NoneStack:   File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py",
> line 355, in _handle__invocation_requestcall_result = await
> self._loop.run_in_executor(File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in
> runresult = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py",
> line 542, in __run_sync_funcreturn func(**params)File
> "/home/site/wwwroot/json-deserialize-eventhub/**init**.py", line 38,
> in maindlc.append_object(obj_converted, data_lake_target_url)File
> "/home/site/wwwroot/shared/datalake.py", line 41, in append_objectfor
> container in file_system_containers:File
> "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/core/paging.py",
> line 129, in __next__return next(self._page_iterator)File
> "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/core/paging.py",
> line 76, in __next__self._response =
> self._get_next(self.continuation_token)File
> "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_models.py",
> line 401, in _get_next_cbprocess_storage_error(error)File
> "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/response_handlers.py",
> line 147, in process_storage_errorraise error

The code itself is simplistic, I basically just use the `DataLakeServiceClient` from the `azure.storage.filedatalake` module to communicate with the data lake.

Why does this not work? How can I allow my function to write/read data? VNet integration is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Maybe you need datalake data owner?

Comment: @BowmanZhu - I tried that but still get "This request is not authorized to perform this operation". When switching "Selected networks" to "All networks" in the Networking menu of the data lake it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#grant-access-from-an-internet-ip-range) is a special case when you configure storage accounts to allow access from specific public internet IP address ranges.

> **Services deployed in the same region as the storage account** use
> private Azure IP addresses for communication. Thus, you cannot
> restrict access to specific Azure services based on their public
> outbound IP address range.

I also see there is a private IP `172.16.0.5` in your screenshots. You could create the same Function APP in another Azure function in the different region from the Azure Data Lake region to verify this.

Comment: Very nicely observed, this indeed works! The problem is: How do I now whitelist these private IPs when I don't want to go down the VNet integration route for the Function? It would be strange if this doesn't work and I have to go the indirect route of putting these two resources into different regions just to enforce them to go the public route which will be a cheaper option (as I don't require a Premium plan for VNet integration)

Comment: Unfortunately, `IP network rules are only allowed for public internet IP addresses. IP address ranges reserved for private networks (as defined in RFC 1918) aren't allowed in IP rules.` Also, I don't think Azure has exposed the underlying infrastructure for the PaaS storage account for us, and we don't know the specific private IP range.

Comment: @christian you have pointed out correctly, this becomes an issue when your azure function makes use of the consumption plan and is hosted in the same region. Moving functions to another region just for this does not appear to be a right solution. Surprised to see that Azure functions is not recognized as 'Trusted Azure Service' from data lake gen2 perspective. Has anyone managed to resolve this or if Microsoft is already working towards addressing this?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, It says HTTP response error: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

So other than add the 'Owner' RBAC role, please also add the 'Storage Blob Data Owner' RBAC role.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix the issue. I gave my function the "Storage Blob Data Owner" role and having "Selected networks" selected in the Networking options: "403 - This request is not authorized to perform this operation". As soon as I switch to "All networks", it works.