# This request is not authorized to perform this operation. I used the class "BlobServiceClient" to connect

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I have read the page with the same problem as I met. 
[This request is not authorized to perform this operation. Azure blobClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130784/this-request-is-not-authorized-to-perform-this-operation-azure-blobclient) 
I have set the IP, and after I used the class "CloudStorageAccount", I can connect to the Azure Storage.
But I want to use another class "BlobContainerClient" which is used as sample code for connecting to Azure emulator "Azurite". 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite#azure-blob-storage 
And I can successfully connect to Azurite in my Docker.
But I will only get the error "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", when I change the connection string to connect to the real Azure Blob Storage.

```
var client = new BlobContainerClient(
new Uri("https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container"),
new StorageSharedKeyCredential("myaccount", $"{AccountKey}"));
```

Here is what my connection string looks like. How can I connect to Azure Storage with this class? Or I should not use this class?

Comment: How about select "All networks" instead of "selected networks" in your storage account?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I select "All networks", I can connect to the Storage with both these two classes.

Comment: So do you need to select "selected networks" in your case?

Comment: Yes, at least currently, I need the setting to remain to  "selected networks".

Comment: This code is running in docker?

Comment: No, the Azurite is in Docker. This code is in my local. And I can use this code to connect to Azurite.

Comment: got it. I'll give it a try and update it later.

Comment: I used the "selected network" option, and added my ip there. Both of the classes can work. Can you please use this cmd command "curl -L ip.tool.lu" to check your real ip, maybe azure detected a wrong ip of your client.

Comment: But if my IP is wrong, both of the classes should fail, right? I tried the command. Then I got another IP like "192.56.xxx.x". But I put the URL "ip.tool.lu" in the browser. I got the same URL as I get in Azure. So the IP should be right. So do you use the class "BlobContainerClient" like how I use it? Or do you add any parameters?

Comment: yes, I used the code in your question, BlobContainerClient can work well. Why I suggest you use the above cmd command? because the first time I add the client ip which azure detects, but then I got the same error as yours. I resolved it by manually add my correct ip address.

Comment: It works, but it seems unreasonable. I get every IP from any webpages are the same. Why is that the IP getting from CMD is different from the IP getting from the browser? Is this because I am using the company network? And Why the class "CloudStorageAccount" can work in the situation? Problem solved, but I get more confused. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When use the "Selected network", due to some reasons, like you're using vpn or proxy etc., the client ip which is detected by azure is not very accurate sometimes.

So you can use this cmd command to find your real client ip: `curl -L ip.tool.lu`. Then manually add it in your azure portal. It works at my side.